# Responsive YouTube embed inside flex

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to have a responsive YouTube embed inside a flex container along with some other content, but the container for the YouTube embed doesn't grow and so either overlaps or is overlapped by other elements. I'm not sure if I've explained this well so I've also made a codesandbox to demonstrate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-mountain-m4dhhb?file=/src/App.js

```
import { Box, Paper } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexFlow: "column wrap",
        gap: 2,
        maxWidth: "960px"
      }}
    >
      <Box>
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            padding: 2
          }}
        >
          <h2>Some content</h2>
          <Box>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
              maximus at enim in sollicitudin. Nam suscipit tellus sit amet
              porttitor hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit. Quisque vel dolor felis. Nulla sodales felis
              iaculis venenatis aliquam. Integer vehicula turpis a mauris
              maximus, eu sagittis ligula dignissim. In faucibus est lacus,
              auctor ornare lacus auctor ut. Morbi vitae ullamcorper nisi.
              Integer non sagittis erat.
            </p>
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            padding: 2
          }}
        >
          <h2>YouTube player</h2>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <iframe
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-opb8DdWBIM"
              title="YouTube video player"
              style={{
                margin: "0 auto",
                width: "100%",
                aspectRatio: "16 / 9"
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            padding: 2
          }}
        >
          <h2>Some other content</h2>
          <p>
            In vehicula a est non tempor. Maecenas ut leo ac arcu sollicitudin
            ullamcorper et vitae lectus. In venenatis lectus purus, non rhoncus
            ante pellentesque a. Sed sollicitudin leo sit amet odio ultricies
            pretium. Mauris eu nibh diam. Sed ante ipsum, efficitur ac leo eget,
            cursus ornare augue. Morbi aliquet porta rhoncus. Quisque ut tellus
            metus. Nam purus arcu, accumsan a dolor at, rhoncus iaculis velit.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
            per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla augue metus, semper id varius sit
            amet, congue vitae nunc. Phasellus interdum arcu quis quam tristique
            porta. Curabitur sit amet imperdiet turpis, ut facilisis mauris.
            Aliquam sit amet commodo nisi. Quisque elementum nulla ac
            ullamcorper interdum. Aliquam interdum sed lorem a tempus.
          </p>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

What can be changed to make it so that the embed's container grows and shrinks with the size of the embedded video?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-morning-85wytv) solution.

1. Wrap the iframe in a container with `position: "relative"` and set its
   `width: "100%"`.
2. Set the container's `paddingBottom` to the required
   aspect ratio value (in percentage). For example, for a 16:9 aspect ratio,
   use `"56.25%"` (9 / 16 * 100%).
3. Set the iframe to be`position:"absolute", top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%", height: "100%"`.
4. To make sure the text under the video does not get hid, set the `flexFlow: "column",`

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```
//Main container box
<Box
    sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexFlow: "column", // Change this line
        gap: 2,
        maxWidth: "960px"
      }}
>
```

Some other code

```
<h2>YouTube player</h2>
<Box
  sx={{
      position: "relative",
      width: "100%",
      paddingBottom: "56.25%", // 9/16 * 100% for 16:9 aspect ratio
  }}
>
    <iframe
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-opb8DdWBIM"
    title="YouTube video player"
    style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        border: 0,
        }}
    />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me using Material-UI's CardMedia

```
<CardMedia component="iframe" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI"
  sx={{
    aspectRatio: "16/9",
  }}
/>
```

CardMedia
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-media/

Aspect Ratio
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio